# For new apps, Android App Bundles must be signed with an RSA key

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I am trying to upload my newly developed app using app bundle in playstore but I am receiving an error saying "For new apps, Android App Bundles must be signed with an RSA key."
When I check Release>Setup>Appintegrity. There is MD5 , SHA-256 and SHA-1  certificate and Download certificate option only. What should i do to sign my app and upload it...Before this I was not getting any error while uploading my apps.

Thank for help.

Comment: There isn't enough information here. How do you sign the app bundle? How did you generate the keystore? Did you use Android Studio or run a command line? It seems that you have generated a key with an unsupported signing algorithm and you might need to generate a new key that is RSA. if you provide the information above, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Build there is GENRATED SIGNED APK option build apk using that and reupload it

Comment: I did this and that is how I got the error.

Comment: upload screen shot of error

Comment: I ended up using my own key.